# How to snap to grid a QGraphicsTextItem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Let be this little snippet:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMenu
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsObject
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QLinearGradient
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsTextItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsItem


def create_action(parent, text, slot=None,
                  shortcut=None, shortcuts=None, shortcut_context=None,
                  icon=None, tooltip=None,
                  checkable=False, checked=False):
    action = QtWidgets.QAction(text, parent)

    if icon is not None:
        action.setIcon(QIcon(':/%s.png' % icon))
    if shortcut is not None:
        action.setShortcut(shortcut)
    if shortcuts is not None:
        action.setShortcuts(shortcuts)
    if shortcut_context is not None:
        action.setShortcutContext(shortcut_context)
    if tooltip is not None:
        action.setToolTip(tooltip)
        action.setStatusTip(tooltip)
    if checkable:
        action.setCheckable(True)
    if checked:
        action.setChecked(True)
    if slot is not None:
        action.triggered.connect(slot)

    return action


class Settings():

    WIDTH = 20
    HEIGHT = 15
    NUM_BLOCKS_X = 32
    NUM_BLOCKS_Y = 16


class CI(QGraphicsTextItem):

    def __init__(self, text, pos):
        QGraphicsTextItem.__init__(self)

        self.content = text
        self.setPlainText(text)

        self.setPos(pos)
        self.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
        self.setDefaultTextColor(Qt.black)
        self.setFlags(
            self.flags() | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setZValue(-1)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.save()
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.white))
        painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())
        painter.restore()

        super().paint(painter, option, widget)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        self.content = self.toPlainText()

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        self.scene().writing_comment = True
        # self.setPlainText(self.content)
        # print("Focusinevent")

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        self.scene().writing_comment = False
        # self.setHtml(self.content)
        # print("FocusOutevent")

    def contextMenuEvent(self, scme):
        super().contextMenuEvent(scme)


class QS(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        width = Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_X * Settings.WIDTH
        height = Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_Y * Settings.HEIGHT
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, width, height)
        self.setItemIndexMethod(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)

        pos = QPoint(
            5 * Settings.WIDTH,
            2 * Settings.HEIGHT
        )
        content = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>This is heading 1</h1>
<h2>This is heading 2</h2>
<h3>This is heading 3</h3>
<h4>This is heading 4</h4>
<h5>This is heading 5</h5>
<h6>This is heading 6</h6>

</body>
</html>
"""
        self.addItem(CI(content, pos))


class QV(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.view_menu = QMenu(self)
        self.create_actions()

    def create_actions(self):
        act = create_action(self.view_menu, "Zoom in",
                            slot=self.on_zoom_in,
                            shortcut=QKeySequence("+"), shortcut_context=Qt.WidgetShortcut)
        self.view_menu.addAction(act)

        act = create_action(self.view_menu, "Zoom out",
                            slot=self.on_zoom_out,
                            shortcut=QKeySequence("-"), shortcut_context=Qt.WidgetShortcut)
        self.view_menu.addAction(act)
        self.addActions(self.view_menu.actions())

    def on_zoom_in(self):
        if not self.scene():
            return

        self.scale(1.5, 1.5)

    def on_zoom_out(self):
        if not self.scene():
            return

        self.scale(1.0 / 1.5, 1.0 / 1.5)

    def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)

        gr = rect.toRect()
        start_x = gr.left() + Settings.WIDTH - (gr.left() % Settings.WIDTH)
        start_y = gr.top() + Settings.HEIGHT - (gr.top() % Settings.HEIGHT)
        painter.save()

        for index, x in enumerate(range(start_x, gr.right(), Settings.WIDTH)):
            if index == Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_X:
                painter.setPen(QtGui.QColor(255, 70, 80).lighter(90))
                painter.setOpacity(0.7)
            else:
                painter.setPen(QtGui.QColor(60, 70, 80).lighter(90))
                painter.setOpacity(0.7)

            painter.drawLine(x, gr.top(), x, gr.bottom())

        for index, y in enumerate(range(start_y, gr.bottom(), Settings.HEIGHT)):
            if index == Settings.NUM_BLOCKS_Y:
                painter.setPen(QtGui.QColor(255, 70, 80).lighter(90))
                painter.setOpacity(0.7)
            else:
                painter.setPen(QtGui.QColor(60, 70, 80).lighter(90))
                painter.setOpacity(0.7)

            painter.drawLine(gr.left(), y, gr.right(), y)

        painter.restore()

        super().drawBackground(painter, rect)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    a = QS()
    b = QV()
    b.setScene(a)
    print(b.mapToScene(b.rect()))
    b.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If we run it we'll see it's creating a little scene with a grid and QGraphicsTextItem on it, like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to figure out here is how to snap the QGraphicsTextItem on the grid intersections **each time I move it or resize it** (when I'm writing some text), how can i guarantee that? Here's a little picture to explain better what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set new width and height of `QGraphicsTextItem` you can overwrite `boundingRect()`, to `setPos()` you can use any appropiate event, `MouseReleaseEvent` or `MouseMoveEvent` for example, and calculate the next top-left grid-intersection from the last `pos()`:

```
class CI(QGraphicsTextItem):

    def __init__(self, text, pos):
        QGraphicsTextItem.__init__(self)

        self.content = text
        self.setPlainText(text)

        self.setPos(pos)
        self.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
        self.setDefaultTextColor(Qt.black)
        self.setFlags(
            self.flags() | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setZValue(-1)

    def boundingRect(self):     
        # get the original width and height of boundingrect
        br = QGraphicsTextItem.boundingRect(self)
        brw = br.width()
        brh = br.height()
        # new width and height in "blocks"
        wblocks = int(brw/Settings.WIDTH) + 1
        hblocks = int(brh/Settings.HEIGHT) + 1
        w = wblocks*Settings.WIDTH
        h = hblocks*Settings.HEIGHT
        return QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, w, h)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):                         
        # QGraphicsItem.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)
        QGraphicsTextItem.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)
        self.setGridIntersection(self.pos())

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        QGraphicsTextItem.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)
        self.setGridIntersection(self.pos())

    def setGridIntersection(self, pos):
        # get the next grid intersection top left of items top-left corner
        grid_x = int(pos.x()/Settings.WIDTH)                        
        grid_y = int(pos.y()/Settings.HEIGHT)
        self.setPos(grid_x*Settings.WIDTH, grid_y*Settings.HEIGHT)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.save()
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.white))
        painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())
        painter.restore()

        super().paint(painter, option, widget)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        self.content = self.toPlainText()

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        self.scene().writing_comment = True
        # self.setPlainText(self.content)
        # print("Focusinevent")

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        self.scene().writing_comment = False
        # self.setHtml(self.content)
        # print("FocusOutevent")

    def contextMenuEvent(self, scme):
        super().contextMenuEvent(scme)
```

Edit 01.02.17:
the solution above is only suitable for singleselections, for both single- and multiselections use:

```
class CI(QGraphicsTextItem):

    def __init__(self, text, pos):
        QGraphicsTextItem.__init__(self)

        self.content = text
        self.setPlainText(text)

        self.setPos(pos)
        self.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
        self.setDefaultTextColor(Qt.black)
        self.setFlags(
            self.flags() | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setZValue(-1)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def boundingRect(self):
        # get the original width and height of boundingrect
        br = QGraphicsTextItem.boundingRect(self)
        brw = br.width()
        brh = br.height()
        # new width and height in "blocks"
        wblocks = int(brw / Settings.WIDTH) + 1
        hblocks = int(brh / Settings.HEIGHT) + 1
        w = wblocks * Settings.WIDTH
        h = hblocks * Settings.HEIGHT
        return QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, w, h)

    def setGridIntersection(self, pos):
        # get the next grid intersection top left of items top-left corner
        grid_x = int(pos.x() / Settings.WIDTH)
        grid_y = int(pos.y() / Settings.HEIGHT)
        self.setPos(grid_x * Settings.WIDTH, grid_y * Settings.HEIGHT)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.save()
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.white))
        painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())
        painter.restore()

        super().paint(painter, option, widget)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        self.content = self.toPlainText()

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        self.scene().writing_comment = True
        # self.setPlainText(self.content)
        # print("Focusinevent")

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        self.scene().writing_comment = False
        # self.setHtml(self.content)
        # print("FocusOutevent")

    def contextMenuEvent(self, scme):
        super().contextMenuEvent(scme)
```

and in class QS add:

```
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)
        for i in self.selectedItems():
            if type(i) == CI:
                i.setGridIntersection(i.pos())
```

Comment: As long as the item stays in the scene, all works fine. If the view is enlarged, the scene has still its first size. So it is possible to move the item out of the scene and the strange behaviour occurs. Draw a rectangle 640 x 240 on the scene to see it. So you have to ensure, that the scene is at least as large as the view and always has the same position on the grid. Pershaps simpler to add the grid to the scene. The capture problem is independent of my code. The mouse can either capture the item or set the cursor in the editor. Only a click on the border almost surely captures the item.

Comment: QGraphicsTextItem.mouseMoveEvent doesn't show this behaviour at me, answer editied

Comment: I used the code you posted in your first comment → strange behaviour. I commented out the last line in mouseMoveEvent → still strange behaviour. I commented out the whole mouseMoveEvent → the item is moved correctly. So there must be a difference between QGraphicsItem.mouseMoveEvent and the mouseMoveEvent usually used by QGraphicsTextItem. So i replaced QGraphicsItem.mouseMoveEvent in mouseMoveEvent by QGraphicsTextItem.mouseMoveEvent and all works as expected.

Comment: i edted my answer

Comment: Thx, still no good cos this solution will have issues when multiple selection is [done](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21334722/Uploads/2017/01/2017-01-30_16-34-34.mp4) but I won't complain anymore cos you've done enough